# How can we create a 'skeleton type' of an object that we should implement?

Tags: javascript, types, flowtype

I want to declare a "skeleton" interface for an object literal that we should implement.

At the time we're creating `AttributeGettersSkeletonType`, we don't know what types the getters will return - only that there *must* be methods called `getColor`, `getMake`, and `getYear` on the object, and that they should return Promises of...something.

But when we implement the object, we know what the type of the promised value will be, and we want to tell flow that.

```js
// @flow strict

type AttributeGettersSkeletonType = {|
  getColor: () => Promise<mixed>,
  getMake: () => Promise<mixed>,
  getYear: () => Promise<mixed>,
|};

const carDetails = ({
  getColor: () => Promise.resolve('blue'),
  getMake: () => Promise.resolve('honda'),
  getYear: (() => Promise.resolve(1994): () => Promise<number>),
}: AttributeGettersSkeletonType);

carDetails.getYear().then(year => {
    const yearPlusOne = year + 1;
})
```

Right now, this produces:

```
16:     const yearPlusOne = year + 1;
                           ^ Cannot add `year` and `1` because mixed [1] could either behave like a string or like a number.
References:
6:   getYear: () => Promise<mixed>,
                            ^ [1]
```

I know one solution would be to refine the type inside the `then` stanza, but I'm hoping there is a way to tell flow the correct type when we create the object. My attempt being `(() => Promise.resolve(1994): () => Promise<number>)`, explicitly providing a more refined type.

Thoughts?

thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for `any` instead of `mixed`?

Comment: Nah - `any` will remove the flow typing from that variable, and allow me to do whatever with it

Comment: Ah I see. I misunderstood your overall issue, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [generic types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/generics/) would generally be used for, e.g.

```
type AttributeGettersSkeletonType<C, M, Y> = {|
  getColor: () => Promise<C>,
  getMake: () => Promise<M>,
  getYear: () => Promise<Y>,
|};

const carDetails = ({
  getColor: () => Promise.resolve('blue'),
  getMake: () => Promise.resolve('honda'),
  getYear: () => Promise.resolve(1994),
}: AttributeGettersSkeletonType<string, string, number>);

carDetails.getYear().then(year => {
    const yearPlusOne = year + 1;
});
```

though I'd probably write the middle part as

```
const carDetails: AttributeGettersSkeletonType<string, string, number> = {
  getColor: () => Promise.resolve('blue'),
  getMake: () => Promise.resolve('honda'),
  getYear: () => Promise.resolve(1994),
};
```

or omit the type declaration entirely until the `carDetails` object is actually passed to a function with that type as a parameter.